# Is Logical && a good replacement of if statement in a branchless POV

Tags: c++, branch

So, i saw sometimes code like this:

```
some_conditions && something();
```

used instead of

```
if(some_conditions) something();
```

Now, i was wondering which of the following versions is the most efficient / better to use:

```
std::vector<int> v{};
v.size() < 10 && (v.push_back(2), 1); // using the comma operator since push_back does not returns anything and so can't be evaluated to bool
```

or

```
std::vector<int> v{};
if(v.size() < 10) v.push_back(2);
```

Comment: The code with the AND operator is used in expressions. If you need not to form an expression then using the if statement can make the code more readable.

Comment: [Try it.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) I bet the compiler generates the same code.

Comment: && is not branchless.

Comment: @chris yes in this case because everything can be deduced at compile time, but it doesn't mean that this will be the same always

Comment: You can try other representative tests. If you're wondering about your production code, you can also test/benchmark that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code segments you have are not branchless, since it still performs conditional logic based on the result of the first comparison. The code generated between the two will generally be the same.

Any optimizing compiler worth their salt should produce identical assemblies. If you compare the output of GCC [on godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ranrvj), both expressions produce the same assembly (only difference being a branch name), and both cases produce branches.

---

In general, you should aim to write code that is readable and not concern yourself for which of the two will be "better for performance". It's far more valuable for your code to be easy to read and maintain. It's only worth optimizing code if you have determined (after profiling) that the code you have written is sub-optimal and causing issues.